# How to check if username already exists in table?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have the REST API app and when I create a user with the same username it creates all the time, but I want the username to be unique cause in real apps username is unique for each user, how can I provide a checking username in DB?
I want my app to throw some message when I create a user with a username that already exists, and of course, do not save a new user  username that already exists

My user Entity:

```
@Table(name = "usr", uniqueConstraints=
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"username", "email"}))
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;

//    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
//    private List<Message> messages;

//    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
//    private List<Comment> comments;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "gender_id")
    private Gender gender;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_subscriptions",
            joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id") ,
            inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id"))
    private Set<User> subscribers;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_subscriptions",
            joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id") ,
            inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id"))
    private Set<User> subscriptions;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_id")
    private FileEntity fileEntity;
```

My user service:

```
@Transactional
    public User save(UserRequest user) {
        provideAllUserCheckingActionsForSave(user);
        User userUntilSave = userMap.userRequestToUser(user,Role.USER,Status.ACTIVE);
        userUntilSave.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userUntilSave.getPassword()));
        User saved = userRepo.save(userUntilSave);
        log.info("User save method invoked");
        return saved;
    }
```

Comment: Spring comes with the ability to add validation to controllers: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html you can write a controller class which will simply call a query to the db to check the username does not already exist.

Comment: Doing a query is not a garantuee. Create a unique index on the username field and catch the exception and show the message you want.

Comment: @M.Deinum can u tell me in more detail?

Comment: You have a unique constraint on both username and email - this means you can have multiple users all with the same username as long as they have different email addresses - only the combination must be unique. You might want separate constraints, one for username and one for email address, so that it throws an exception if a username is used for someone else.

Comment: @Chris can u tell me in more detail?

Comment: Top of your class @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"username", "email"})). This creates a single unique constraint that uses both of these fields, which cannot be what you want, but seems close, like an attempt to solve this problem. Remove the email from the constraint so it is just on username and you will prevent non-unique usernames from being added to the DB. IF you need unique email addresses, you must add a separate constraint @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={ "email"})), just on the email, unless you want the same email address to be usable by multiple users.

Comment: Following up on @Chris, check this guide here: baeldung.com/jpa-unique-constraints#3-multiple-unique-constraints-on-a-single-entity
It includes entities with multiple unique columns.

Comment: @Chris I changed it to two separate constraints but when I post my new user with the same username in postman the program creates him all the time.

Comment: The constraints must get generated in the database - how is the schema and tables being setup? Make sure you drop and create the DB from the JPA metadata to have the changes generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @unique annotation to store the unique values in the database and if it throws the exception for not taking the unique value the exception should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Before create user,you can search user by username,if search result is empty,then create new user,if search result is not empty,deal the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add validation to the controller or you can simply do it as follows:- When a user wants to register, get the username and search in the database whether it already exists or not. If findByUsername(username) returns null then perform the next operation and register the user, else return some error message.